# OData - Strange index with MongoDB [Mongoose: Cast Error]

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, odata, jaydata

I have some MongoDB documents with this schema:

```
Id: {type: "id", key: true, computed: true, nullable: false},
Name: {type: "string", nullable: false, maxLength: 50}
```

and these documents are exposed as OData by a small web application (I'm using Express, JayData, and Mongoose).
These are some of those documents:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5343fd656b9c5c084b8f2a70"), "Name" : "Service74"},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5343fd656b9c5c084b8f2a6f"), "Name" : "Service73"},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5343fd656b9c5c084b8f2a6e"), "Name" : "Service72"},
...
```

If I type this address `http://localhost:8080/marketplace/Services('5343fd656b9c5c084b8f2a70')` which correspond to *Service74* I get this result:

```
...
<d:Id>NTM0M2ZkNjU2YjljNWMwODRiOGYyYTcw</d:Id>
<d:Name>Service74</d:Name>
...
```

Of course If I use the Id specified in the result I obtain the same page.

The problem occurs when I try to use the mongoose function *findById*:

```
app.post("/addCompare/:id", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.id);
    Services.findById(req.params.id, function(err, service) {
        if(!err) {console.log(service);}
        else {console.log(err);}
    });
    res.send(200);
});
```

I get this `NTM0M2ZkNjU2YjljNWMwODRiOGYyYTcw` and then this error:

```
{ message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "NTM0M2ZkNjU2YjljNWMwODRiOGYyYTU5" at path "_id"',
  name: 'CastError',
  type: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'NTM0M2ZkNjU2YjljNWMwODRiOGYyYTU5',
  path: '_id' }
```

Where am I wrong? Tell me if I miss some other information...

Thanks.

PS: I found a similar problem here [Mongoose: Cast to ObjectId failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268787/mongoose-cast-to-objectid-failed), but if I change the model definition for Mongoose (in which actually I don't declare the id) by including this definition:

```
var serviceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String,
    ...
```

nothing changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `5343fd656b9c5c084b8f2a70` is the internal identifier of the entity that is used on the server-side. This value is base64-encoded over OData, this is why you receive `NTM0M2ZkNjU2YjljNWMwODRiOGYyYTcw` in the Id field. The entity can be easily retrieved by Id by calling `atob(req.params.id)` on the received Id.